# Multitasking while running SMART tests?

Tags: windows-7, smart

Does it affect anything if you multitask (windows 7 x64) while running SMART tests to scan for HDD errors?

Answer (score 2):

It should not, excluding the 'offline tests' smart operations.  Even with those I'd be surprised if you saw anything more significant than a small performance difference.  Most SMART operations only involve the drive firmware and not the platters where your data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "running SMART tests" some clarification needs to be made.

**From this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.):**

> The purpose of S.M.A.R.T. is to warn a user or a system administrator of impending drive failure while there is still time to take action, such as copying the data to a replacement device.

S.M.A.R.T. is a series of built-in self tests that are run and monitored by the hard drive.  **Viewing** these results can be done at any time whether using the hard drive or not. There is really no "testing" done, but rather a viewing of these already monitored tests.

However if you do **any** diagnostics on the drive then there is a *possibility* that something might happen.  My recommendation is to avoid testing your hard drive while doing **any** sort of tasks.  Also be sure to make backups of the data.  It's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: I think this is bad advice.  SMART is explicitly intended for online operation, and it's been in use for around a decade at this point.  The risk of 'something' happening to a good drive are nil.